# Mysql on XAMPP server wont start.

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm trying to start mysql server but it gives following error log. I tried to change port number. But it is no worth

```
2014-09-26 09:31:23 3880 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-09-26 09:31:23 f34 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-09-26 09:31:23 3880 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-09-26 09:31:23 3880 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-09-26 09:31:23 3880 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-09-26 09:31:23 3880 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-09-26 09:31:23 3880 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-09-26 09:31:23 3880 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2014-09-26 09:31:23 3880 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-09-26 09:31:23 3880 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-09-26 09:31:23 3880 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 3997169
2014-09-26 09:31:23 3880 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2014-09-26 09:31:23 3880 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2014-09-26 09:31:23 3880 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2014-09-26 09:31:24 3880 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2014-09-26 09:31:24 3880 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 3997285
2014-09-26 09:31:24 3880 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-09-26 09:31:25 3880 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-09-26 09:31:25 3880 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.16 started; log sequence number 3997285
2014-09-26 09:31:25 3880 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-09-26 09:31:25 3880 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-09-26 09:31:25 3880 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-09-26 09:31:25 3880 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2014-09-26 09:31:25 3880 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'user'
```

Comment: At least one of the table files in `C:\your\xampp\mysql\data\mysql` seems to be defect. Did you have the issue right after installation, or does this error only occur recently?

Comment: this error occurred since today. yesterday it was worked fine

Comment: I've added some suggestions as an answer, have a look into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is shown here:

```
2014-09-26 09:31:25 3880 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'user'
```

At least one of the table files in `C:\your\xampp\mysql\data\mysql\user*` seems to be defect. Since this is vital for the server, therefore it can't start.

Possible ways to deal with this:

- If you have the issue right after installation, try a re-install.
- If you have the issue only recently, restore `C:\your\xampp\mysql\data\mysql\user*` from a recent backup.
- If you have no backup, you might even install another mysql instance somewhere else and copy the files `C:\your\new\mysql\data\mysql\user*` into `C:\your\xampp\mysql\data\mysql\`. Since this will only contain the default users, you'll have to manually add users you've worked with in your old, corrupt installation.

Answer (score 12):

Copy this 3 files:

- user.frm
- user.MYD
- user.MYI

from C:\xampp\mysql\backup\mysql
to
C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql

and override it.

Comment: Awesome! Worked great!

Comment: This worked, but what could have caused the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I also suffered this same problem. But my Data was very important for me. I also looks online, but not get any kind of solving.
Then I solved this issue and also get back my all data on the database.
This is my server path: D:\server\mysql\data
Solving:

Step-1: Go to D:\server\mysql\data

then copy all folder of database and also  **ibdata1** this file.

Step-2: Cut full folder of htaccess outside of your server folder.

Step-3: Then Uninstall xmapp then install same version of xmapp on the same location,
then replace all files by backup files.

Step-4: Re-start your xmapp.

Then go to your database, you will get all data and everything will be work fine.
But if you look on your mysql errors log, the problem coming yet. That's not solved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue Mysql not running on Xampp. I got the 3 user* files from other colleague system and copied/overwrite to my system in the C:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql/ folder. It worked.